# JSBin: How to get ES6/Babel tab?

Tags: javascript, jsbin

I am learning JavaScript. I am using online editor [Jsbin](https://jsbin.com/) to run javascript. I want to use ES6 with Babel. I have seen some of the tutorials or JSBins which has babel tab in the editor. Please refer the screenshot for more detail. I am not able to figure out how do we get this `ES6/Babel` tab in JSbin. Can anyone please help me on this? Thanks.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In the Javascript pane, click the "Javascript" dropdown in the top left and change to "ES6/Babel":

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: In the account preferences ("Default Preferences"->"Linting"->"JSHint") set appropriate value for "esversion" property.